# take differences between consecutive pairs of rows

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable computed from the difference between two pairs of rows that are consecutive (1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, 7 and 8, 9 and 10 etc.) I am using the lag function but currently getting the difference between all consecutive rows (1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4 etc.) How do I just get the differences between pairs of rows, in intervals of 2?

Here is the example with mtcars data:

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(diff_mpg = mpg - lag(mpg))
```

Comment: `mtcars %>% group_by(row = (row_number()+1) %/%2) %>% summarise(diff_mpg = mpg[1] - mpg[2])`

Answer (score 1):

You can group the rows then lag.

```
final <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(row_group = rep(1:nrow(.), each = 2, length.out = nrow(.))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(row_group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(diff_mpg = mpg - lag(mpg)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)  # or remove if you want to keep NAs
```

Answer (score 1):

Group then do the difference:

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(row = (row_number()+1) %/%2) %>%
   summarise(diff_mpg = mpg[1] - mpg[2])

# A tibble: 16 × 2
     row diff_mpg
   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1    0    
 2     2    1.40 
 3     3    0.600
 4     4  -10.1  
 5     5    3.6  
 6     6    1.40 
 7     7    2.10 
 8     8    0    
 9     9  -17.7  
10    10   -3.5  
11    11    6    
12    12    1.90 
13    13   -8.1  
14    14   -4.4  
15    15   -3.9  
16    16   -6.4
```

---

If you need to `mutate` include `NA` in order to have size 2.

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(row = (row_number()+1) %/%2) %>% 
   mutate(diff_mpg = c(NA, mpg[1] - mpg[2]))
# A tibble: 32 × 13
# Groups:   row [16]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   row diff_mpg
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4     1   NA    
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4     1    0    
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     2   NA    
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1     2    1.40 
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     3   NA    
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1     3    0.600
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4     4   NA    
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2     4  -10.1  
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2     5   NA    
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4     5    3.6
```

Comment: thank you! i see how the row_number function is useful for creating a new variable to label the consecutive rows by a grouping variable

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` *mpg* at `1:2` (which will recycle) and use `-` in `Reduce`. `replace` an `NA`-`array` of `length(mpg)` with the values.

```
> transform(
+   mtcars, 
+   dif=replace(array(,length(mpg)), seq_len(length(mpg)/2)*2, Reduce(`-`, split(mpg, 1:2)))
+ )
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   dif
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   0.0
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   1.4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    NA
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   0.6
```

Note that this throws a warning if `nrow(mtcars)` is odd, but this can be ignored.